# Verilog, using enum with don't cares

Tags: enums, typedef, system-verilog

Is it possible to use enum with don't cares? I've tried the following

```
typedef enum reg [31:0] {
   BLTZ  = 32'b000001_?????_00000_????????????????,
   BGEZ  = 32'b000001_?????_00001_????????????????,
   BEQ   = 32'b000100_?????_?????_????????????????, 
   BNE   = 32'b000101_?????_?????_????????????????,
   .
   .
   .
```

Then using the syntax given by [doulos.com](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/sysverilog/tutorial/datatypes/), I tried the following to see if I can get an "ADD" instruction to be displayed on the waveform viewer

```
   op_mne_e op_mnemonic;
   assign op_mnemonic = op_mne_e'(32'b000000_?????_?????_?????_?????_10000);
```

but what I see is

```
000000zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz10000
```

Is it possible to have something similar to a casez for enum?

Comment: I changed the tag to System-Verilog, because there are no `typedef`s or `enum`s in Verilog. I realise that might make your question seem like it has disappeared to you. Hence this comment, which will appear in your Recent Inbox Messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the tags to this question, because you are asking about *System-Verilog*, not Verilog. What we call Verilog is now a subset of the System-Verilog standard, IEEE-1800.

In System-Verilog, enumeration types have an underlying *base type*. By default this type is `int`, which is a 2-state type (each bit can only take the values `0` or `1`). You can specify other base types if you wish. Each member of the enumeration type is represented by a different value of the type of the base type.

You have specified a 4-state, 32-bit base type: `reg [31:0]`*. Those 4 states are `0`, `1`, `Z` (or `?`) and `X`. So, each member of the enumeration type is represented by a 4-state value, ie some combination of `0`, `1`, `Z` (or `?`) and `X`. But, when you display the value with a "%b" format specifier, that's what you get: you get the underlying 4-state value (using `Z`s, not `?`s).

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3khr

In a `casez` statement, a `Z` or a `?` represents a don't care. So, you can use an such an `enum` with a 4-state base type in a `casez` statement if you wish:

```
 casez (op_mnemonic) 
   BLTZ : $display("BLTZ");
   BGEZ : $display("BGEZ");
   BEQ  : $display("BEQ");
   BNE  : $display("BNE");
 endcase
```

but, as we're speaking System-Verilog here, why not use `case ... inside` instead?

```
 case (op_mnemonic) inside
   BLTZ : $display("BLTZ");
   BGEZ : $display("BGEZ");
   BEQ  : $display("BEQ");
   BNE  : $display("BNE");
 endcase
```

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4g3J

`case ... inside` is usually considered safer than the old `casez`, because it exhibits *asymmetrical wildcard matching*. In other words, unlike in a `casez`, in a `case ... inside` an `X` or `Z` (or `?`) in the test expression (`op_mnemonic` in this case) does not act like a don't care (but does in the branch expression, of course).

*It would be more usual in System-Verilog to specify `logic [31:0]`, which is identical, but `logic` is usually used in System-Verilog in preference to `reg`.

Comment: '?' and 'z' are equivalent in Verilog.

Comment: Thanks @dave_59. Whilst I knew `Z` and `?` were synonyms in a `casez` statement, I hadn't realised it was more general than that. The penny has dropped re the original question, now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the labels of your enum variable displayed in the waveform, you will need to set the radix to display it. Most tools default to displaying in binary.  SystemVerilog has a number of operators that treat 'z' as a don't care (`casez` is one of them) so '?' is allowed as part of a numeric literal in place of a 'z'. However, that '?' gets immediately converted over to a 'z' and you will never see a '?' printed out.

If you are trying to assign a value to an enum and have it decode the instruction and pick a matching label, that won't work. You would need to loop the the enum values and use the wildcard equality operator `==?` to find a match.

But if you are only doing this to get a label in the waveform, Modelsim/Questa has a `radix define` command that will decode the instruction for you.